# Is an Option type smaller than the wrapped type plus a boolean?

Tags: struct, rust, boolean, padding, option-type

```rust
use std::mem::size_of;

struct Position {
    x: f32,
    y: f32,
    z: f32,
}

struct PoolItem {
    entity_id: u32, // 4 bytes
    used: bool, // 1 bytes + 3 (padding)
    component: Position, // 12 bytes
}


assert_eq!(size_of::<u32>(), 4);
assert_eq!(size_of::<Position>(), 12);
assert_eq!(size_of::<PoolItem>(), 20);
```

As you can see, such a structure is 20 bytes long. `Position` is actually optional and depends on `used`.

Will the use of [`Option`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/) remove the need of the `used` field and decrease the structure size to 16?

```rust
struct PoolItem {
    entity_id: u32, // 4 bytes
    component: Option<Position>, // 12 bytes ?
}
```

If so, how is `Option` implemented for such a behavior to work?

My tests on [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c862ed0323f00ed76f24c1084bc57056) seem to indicate it doesn't work. Why?

Comment: Original question was: “Can `Option` type removes the need of a boolean field?”. The edited version lose the hint IMHO.

Comment: What's the "hint" that is lost? You can feel free to edit the question again if my edit violated the spirit of the question; it seemed to me the main thrust of the question was to ask whether using `Option` would decrease the size of `PoolItem` vs. using a `bool` (to which the answer is no). In any case, my edit was made after the first two answers were already posted, so both answerers were responding to your original question, not my edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Option<Position>` needs to store the state (`Some` or `None`) *somewhere*, and because `Position` already contains 12 bytes of information, you need more space to store it. Usually this means that it adds an extra byte (plus padding) to store the state, although in some cases where the inner type has a known unused state. For example, a reference can point to address `0`, so `Option<&'_ T>` could use `0` as the `None` state and take up the same number of bytes as `&'_ T`. For your `Position` type, however, that's not the case.

If you absolutely need your `PoolItem` struct to be as small as possible, and if you can spare one bit from your `entity_id` field (say, the highest bit, 2<sup>31</sup>), you can use that to store the state instead:

```rust
const COMPONENT_USED_BIT: u32 = (1u32 << 31);

struct PoolItem {
    entity_id: u32, // lowest 31 bits = entity ID, highest bit = "component used"
    component: Position,
}
```

This might become a bit complex, since you need to ensure that you're treating that bit specially, but you can write a couple of simple accessor methods to ensure that the special bit is dealt with correctly.

```rust
impl PoolItem {
    /// Get entity ID, without the "component used" bit
    fn entity_id(&self) -> u32 {
        self.entity_id & !COMPONENT_USED_BIT
    }

    /// Set entity ID, keeping the existing "component used" bit
    fn set_entity_id(&mut self, entity_id: u32) {
        let component_used_bit = self.entity_id & COMPONENT_USED_BIT;
        self.entity_id = (entity_id & !COMPONENT_USED_BIT) | component_used_bit;
    }

    /// Get component if "component used" bit is set
    fn component(&self) -> Option<&Position> {
        if self.entity_id & COMPONENT_USED_BIT != 0 {
            Some(&self.component)
        } else {
            None
        }
    }

    /// Set component, updating the "component used" bit
    fn set_component(&mut self, component: Option<Position>) {
        if let Some(component) = component {
            self.component = component;
            self.entity_id |= COMPONENT_USED_BIT;
        } else {
            self.entity_id &= !COMPONENT_USED_BIT;
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground example with tests](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=6c59d0770f77e618d3e08f26be4dfa5b)

Comment: What about [`NonZeroU32`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/num/struct.NonZeroU32.html)?

Comment: @Narann `NonZeroU32` and similar types allow the same compiler optimizations as references (since `0` is not a valid state), so `Option<NonZeroU32>` takes up as many bytes as `NonZeroU32`.

Comment: Of course, but wouldn't `Option<NonZeroU32>` avoids dealing with bit masks?

Comment: @Narann Yes, it would, I guess, but as the question is written, it asks about making the `component` field optional. Using `Option<NonZeroU32>` would make the `entity_id` field optional, which is not the same. As I've described, it's not possible to make the `Position` type optional without increasing the size (or decreasing the size of something else, as in my answer).

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately, the question has been edited and changed the hint. Original question was: “Can Option type removes the need of a boolean field?”

Answer (score 5):

The precise implementation of `Option` doesn't really matter. What's obvious is that you can't store `X` amount of data in `X` amount of storage *and* also store whether or not data is there at all. An obvious implementation for `Option` would be to store both object and a boolean indicating if the object exists; clearly something like that is happening. `Option` is a convenience, it still has to store the information somewhere.

Note that outside of a `struct` (which must have consistent size) `Option` might avoid this cost, if the optimizer determines the `Option` has known "populated or not" status at all times, so the boolean *might* be elided in favor of the code always using it deterministically in the correct way (either reading the object from the stack if it logically exists, or not doing so when it doesn't). But in this case, the extra data is needed.

Comment: Since `Position` can never be a null pointer, the absence of `Position` could be encoded as null pointer, while the presence as the pointer to the `Position` object itself. It does not seem to be so, but until now I believed that `Option` was encoded this way and that "Zero-cost-abstraction" was the keyword for this behavior.

Comment: There's no pointer. The 12 bytes of `Position` are embedded directly in the parent struct.

Comment: Worth noting that changing entity_id to be a NonZeroU32 would allow the Option layout optimization to happen, with the small cost of having entities starting from id 1.

Comment: @CoronA: Beyond JohnKugelman's point, a pointer wouldn't be zero cost either. You'd be paying 4-8 bytes for the pointer, and the whole cost of the `Position` (along with allocator overhead) on top of that. And worse, you'd have to perform pointer lookup to "somewhere else" memory (may not be in cache line/page, and therefore goes much slower), where embedding the object directly avoids that expense (both the boolean and the object are adjacent, and should typically be in the same cache line). Avoiding that means allocating them in a block, and now you're using a pointer as a glorified boolean.

Comment: @CoronA It's worthwhile to note that if you did put `Position` behind a non-nullable pointer, such as a `Box<Position>`, `&Position` or `Rc<Position>`, the compiler would in fact encode it as you suggest. "Zero-cost abstraction" is a general term usually applied when comparing a built-in abstraction (like an `Option<T>`) to a rhetorical hand-coded equivalent (like a struct containing a `T` and a boolean flag). In this sense, `Option<T>` is indeed zero-cost, because even if the flag is necessary, it wouldn't be possible to hand-code it any better.

Answer (score -2):

As suggested in the comments, an alternative would be to use `Option` with [`NonZeroU32`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/num/struct.NonZeroU32.html) for `entity_id` and rely on `Some` and `None` to check entity is used or not.

```rust
struct PoolItem {
    entity_id: Option<core::num::NonZeroU32>, // 4 bytes
    component: Position, // 12 bytes
}

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(size_of::<u32>(), 4);
    assert_eq!(size_of::<Position>(), 12);
    assert_eq!(size_of::<PoolItem>(), 16);
}
```

It makes entity ids starting from `1`.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=959847055ff30b7923c9ee97329a8415)

Comment: This isn't the same as what the OP was asking about. They have an `entity_id` and optional `component`; you have a `component` and optional `entity_id`. It's not possible to use the niche in `entity_id` to encode the presence or absence of a `Position`. Frxstrem's answer shows how you can restrict the range of `entity_id` to do this correctly (but you need to use a whole bit of `entity_id`, not just the one niche value).

Comment: I'm OP, and my original question has been edited. Original question was: “Can Option type removes the need of a boolean field?”. But you're technically right. Using `Option<NonZeroU32>` implies `entity_id` is `NonZeroU32` almost everywhere else in the code base.

Comment: Yes, I edited it, and I don't see how the edit has anything to do with this answer. The question, both before and after the edits, asks how to make a struct with an ID and optional `Position`; this answer shows how to make a struct with a `Position` and optional ID. You cannot use this struct to encode the value `PoolItem { entity_id: 704, component: None }`, for example, as you can with `Option<Position>`. Making `entity_id` optional is not isomorphic to making `Position` optional.